# Ceiling Expression

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

I might be over complicating things a bit, or I just want to verify that this is correct.

two positive integers $m$ and $n$ such that  $⌈(m+n)/12⌉  ≠   ⌈m/12⌉+⌈n/12⌉$, where $⌈⌉$ indicate the ceiling function.

Do I just need to find any 2 positive integers, 8 and 4, to plug into $m$ and $n$ so that when I divide by 12 I get $1$ and the ceiling of a whole number is that same whole number? Or is there an actual method to finding out the numbers for $m$ and $n$?

Comment: The point isn’t to get the ceiling to be a whole number: it’s to choose $m$ and $n$ so that $$\left\lceil\frac{m+n}{12} \right\rceil\ne\left\lceil\frac{m}{12}\right\rceil+ \left\lceil\frac{n}{12}\right\rceil\;.$$ The choice $m=8$ and $n=4$ will in fact work, because the lefthand side is $1$, while the righthand side is $1+1=2$, but taking $m=n=1$ would work just as well, and for the same reason.

Comment: Thank you. I thought it was that easy.

Comment: You’re welcome.